# what does this do??? /[\\/]electron-prebuilt[\\/]/.test()

Tags: javascript, if-statement, webpack, escaping, electron

I cloned a [Electron React Boilerplate](https://github.com/pbarbiero/basic-electron-react-boilerplate) repo and in the [main.js](https://github.com/pbarbiero/basic-electron-react-boilerplate/blob/master/main.js) saw this in the code:

`if ( process.defaultApp || /[\\/]electron-prebuilt[\\/]/.test(process.execPath)`

I know this is regex, but I do not understand why or what is happening here. Why would you need this?  `/[\\/]`

I have never seen this. I also do not have a keyword to search Google because I have no reference term to search.

Comment: it's a regular expression. You'd know that if you looked up javascript syntax.

Comment: Copy the regex in [regexpal.com](http://www.regexpal.com/), it'll explain you everything.

Comment: zzzzBov. No. I would not have known and still do not.

Comment: I understand this is a regex, but what is the purpose? Jermeny Thille, I do not see anything happening because it wants to compare a string. I get it that it is a regex, that does not explain what is happening here.

Comment: @MichaelBruce it sounds like you need to [do more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/497418) then.

Comment: @zzzzBov dude... no.

Answer (score 2):

It's testing to see what environment it's in. If any of those regexs match the process.defaultApp or evaluate to true then it knows it must be in a development environment and not a production environment. This is helpful if you want to run some code in dev (say log in details, or debug messages) but not in production then you would test for these kinds of conditions. You can see how they use it here https://github.com/pbarbiero/basic-electron-react-boilerplate/blob/master/main.js#L46 They're popping up dev tools if you're developing and not if it's  a production app

Specificaly it's using the `/[\\/]` to check if somewhere in the path it references electron-prebuilt. The `[]` matches any character within the brackets and then depending on your Operating system it may have forward slashes or backward slashes `/ \` but if you want a backslash you need to escape it first hence the `\\`

Like for example C:/users/blah/someOtherFolder/electron-prebuilt/etc/etc

If it's being executed from there you can assume it's not a deployed production app.

Comment: I am unsure still what this does. It is not the regex that I question. it is the use in the if statement. Is this some kind of special call for a module? Is this a Node thing? I am trying to figure out what this is called.

Comment: It's an environment check. It could be for a lot of things but mainly to see if you're developing or if it's in production. You might have a url that you want to point elsewhere "www.somewhere.local" while you're developing and testing and then "www.somewhere.com" on live when people are using it. It's not specifically a node thing but it does get used quite a bit with the tool chain based workflow that javascript has been trending towards lately.

Comment: Chris. I truly understand that it is an environment check, what I do not get is what is electron-prebuilt? like why would it recognize this if it is not imported. I did not import electron-prebuilt. On top of that, what exactly is this regex doing that is interacting with the node / js system?

Comment: electron-prebuilt is the whole electron application downloaded locally using npm. The boilerplate you are using uses electron-prebuilt as a dependency so it can run your app. Without electron-prebuilt it wouldn't be an electron app. You can always look this info up using github https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-prebuilt this gives you all the info you need to know on it.